# In XAML, how best to duplicate the functionality of hiding an HTML <div>

Tags: powershell, xaml, user-interface

Work continues on migrating my HTA to a Powershell-driven, XAML-based form...

Parts of the HTA use the "STYLE='display:[none|blank];'" technique to show/hide parts of the dialog box when, for example, the user changes the selection in a drop-down box.

What is the *simplest* way to do this in XAML?

99% of the XAML I have is inside a 'Canvas' tag. Can I use more of those and set their visibility on/off? Obviously I could set each separate element's visibility but life's too short for that nonsense, right?

It *looks* like 'StackPanel' will do the job but does hiding that control hide all the controls encapsulated by it?

Comment: Can you add an example to your question? It sounds like you **do** want to set the visibility. Are you looking for something like the Expander control?

Comment: I have no example, since I don't yet know which control would be best. Maybe a fulller explanation will help.

I have 3 scenarios for the user to choose from, options for which are listed in a drop-down. There is a default setting which displays a number of check-boxes, another drop-down and some text-boxes. 1/2

Comment: When the user selects the 2nd option from the drop-down, the default controls are swapped out for a different set of check-boxes, a single drop-down and a date-picker.

The third selection swaps out the above and draws a further different set of check-boxes, 3 drop-downs and a text-box.

As I mentioned, hiding/revealing those individually will produce a spaghetti of code that I want to avoid. 2/2

Comment: Each control has a Visibility property that you can set to hidden/visible.

Comment: @VBScab Maybe you just want a `ContentControl` like the answer here talks about: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2130193/7411885 . Add your other controls to it and toggle its visibility. You could also use more `Canvas` tags or the other types of `Panel`, depending on how you want to organize things. It will be easier to build a proof of concept and see whether they work for yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested grids have worked a treat! For now, there is a shed-load of duplicate code but I'll come to that when more of the core functionality is done.

Many thanks for all your pointers, folks! I appreciate it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer so that I can format the text.

@RetiredGeek I believe I mentioned that I know I can set each control's visibility but my code is already getting spaghetti-like without an extra 90-odd lines enabling/disabling that property. –

@Cpt.Whale I just tried a ContentControl but because I'm loading the XAML from a file, I get this error:

> WARNING: XML Load failed with error: Exception calling "Load" with "1"
> argument(s): "'Content' property has already been set on
> 'ContentControl'." Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s):
> "'Content' property has already been set on 'ContentControl'." At
> [path_to_my_project]\test.ps1:58 char:2 –

Here's how I'm loading the XAML:

```
$InputXAML_FullName = Convert-Path $ScriptDir\Form.xaml

# Load the file
$InputXAML = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($InputXAML_FullName)

#===========================================================================
# Remove stuff we don't want
#===========================================================================

$InputXAML = $InputXAML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N' -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'

#===========================================================================
# Read the cleaned-up XAML
#===========================================================================

[xml]$xmlDoc = $InputXAML

$XAML_Reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xmlDoc)

Try {
    $Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($XAML_Reader)
}
Catch {
    Write-Warning "XML Load failed with error: $($Error[0])"
    Throw
}
```

I think I'm going to have to re-jig my grids and use a nested grid inside one of them.